# To move a txt file from one folder to another if it crosses a certain size limit .

Tags: batch-file, copy

How to move a txt file from one folder to another if it crosses a certain size limit, say for 1MB. I want a batch file so that I can schedule it on daily basis, as I am doing it for large number of files at a time.

I found certain code in this forum but I need some help in adding the condition I have mentioned.
Any help?

Code I found:

```
 @echo off
  set src_folder=c:\whatever\
  set dst_folder=c:\foo
  FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (input.txt) DO COPY "%%a" "%destfolder%\%%~nxa"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is actually valuable then use [*robocopy*](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) instead of copy or move (move may be faster on local disk). One of the things *robocopy* does is it ensures no deletion happens until the copy is succeeded, it is also **very** resilient to problems with network disks. *Robocopy* also has lot of extra features such as checking changes to the folder periodically for changes, making sure timestamps dont change, selection based on age etc... One of the features is copying only based on the size of your file (*/min* or even */max* if your so inclined). 
This is exactly the kind of scenario *robocopy* was meant to handle.

```
@echo off
set src_folder=c:\whatever\
set dst_folder=c:\foo
robocopy src_folder dst_folder /mov /min:1048576
```

The */mov* flag moves the files (or actually deletes it after its been copied and possibly verified for copy errors if you wish) once its done. *Robocopy* also knows how to handle whole folders with the */move* flag.

Comment: hey i need to add in one more condition.I need to find a specific string say "Error" in a txt file.If the txt file contains it ,then it should be moved to a specific folder

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (input.txt) DO if %%~za gtr 1048576 MOVE "%%a" "%destfolder%\%%~nxa"
```

should dow aht you ask. `%%~za` returns the length of `%%a`. `MOVE` moves the file whereas `COPY` copies it, so you'd simply execute the `COPY` on each invication.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
  set src_folder=c:\whatever\
  set dst_folder=c:\foo
  set /a max_size_in_mb=1
  set /a max_size=%max_size_in_mb%*1048576 
  FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (input.txt) DO (
     echo size is %%~za bytes 
     rem this is in 1mb case
     if %%~za GEQ %max_size% move /Y "%%a" "%destfolder%\%%~nxa"
 )
```